# Laravel Eloquent - many to many with where for the pivot table

Tags: laravel-4, eloquent

I'm trying to see what the best way to do the following.

I have 3 tables: users, items and item_user.

users and items table are pretty generic, id and a few columns to hold whatever data.

item_user table has the following structure
id
item_id
user_id
user_type [ 1 - Owner | 2 - Follower | 3 - Something else ]

Relationships:
Each Item has 1 Owner (user type)
Each Item has many followers
Each User can own many Items
Each User can follow many Items

I would like to have the Owner and Followers be the Users table so I don't need to replicate user data.  I created a pivot table of item_id, user_id and user_type to hold these relationships.

So the question is how to I do this in Laravel Eloquent?

Item Model looks like:

```
public function user() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('Users');
    // This isn't actually correct since it belongs to only one User but not sure how to specify a where user_type = 1;
    // return $this->belongsTo('User');
}
```

User Model looks like:

```
public function item() {
    return $this->hasMany('Item');
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can just append the condition to your `belongsToMany` declaration:

```
public function user() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('Users')->where('user_type', 1);
}
```

This will return only the `User` entries that have `user_type = 1` in your pivot table. And just to make it more clear you could name the method `owner()` instead of `user()` to reflect the added condition.